# HttpCacheability.Private Not working as expected

Tags: asp.net, caching

I have some small data objects that I need to cache on the client.  It is user information like their name and their role.  I have the HttpCacheability.Private set.  When I use Fiddler to view the page, I can see that caching is Private but instead of storing the cache for each user, when a different user navigates to the site it is displaying the cached values for the user that logged in first.  I seems like it is storing the server value.

For instance the cache expires in 10 minutes.  After the cache is expired I go to the site.  The cache is null so it looks up my user info from the db (based on Current logged in user) and writes it to cache.  Now John Doe goes to the site 3 minutes after I do and he see my information displayed instead of his.

I'm not sure what else I need to do to cache each user's information on their client and not the server.  Any help would be apprecated.

Thanks,

Rhonda

```
public static void AddUserToCache(User userToCache, string Key)
    {
        HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
        HttpCachePolicy cachePolicy = context.Response.Cache;
        cachePolicy.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Private);

        if (context.Cache[Key] == null)
        {
            context.Cache.Add(Key, userToCache, null, System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, new TimeSpan(UIConstants.CACHETIMEOUTHOURS, 0, 0), System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority.Default, null);
        }
    }




if (Cache["User"] == null)
        {
            user = BusinessUtility.GetCurrentUser();
            if (user != null)
            {
                CacheUtility.AddUserToCache(user, "User");

            }

        }
        else
        {
            user = (User)Cache["User"];
        }
```

Comment: I should also mention that in the original version of my code I didn't have the cachepolicy stuff as Private should be the default.  It doesn't work either way.

Answer (score 0):

`context.Cache` is a server side cache and that's where that data lives.  There is no way to change that.  Data stored in there will only be accessible via server side code.

On the other hand, `context.Response.Cache` is a directive, passed as http headers, that tells the browser and intermediate proxies, whether or not to cache the response from the server to the browser.

So the next step is to figure out a little more about what you are trying to accomplish by caching the data.  Are you trying to reduce hits from the webserver to the database or reduce hits to the webserver altogether?

If you are trying to reduce DB hits, then stick with the `context.Cache` code, change it so that the key has some unique identifier as to which user your are storing/retrieving.  Get rid of the `cachePolicy.SetCacheability` to start with so it doesn't confuse things.

If you are trying to reduce hits to the webserver, stick with the `cachePolicy.SetCacheability` code and get rid of the `context.Cache` code for now.

Comment: Trying to reduce hits to the database.  I added a unique id to the key and will test it on the server.  Thanks for responding.